# Laravel: Should I use web middleware on this ajax call

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a basic Laravel 5.4 web application that uses the default Authentication features.  Most requests are full page loads.  Their routes are set up in `web.php`, and are therefore subject to the web middleware.

There are a few URI's which receive XHR requests, such as `/new-user/check-existing-email`.  As far as I can see, these also need to go in `web.php`, and be subject to the web middleware.  Is that correct?

Comment: I would do something like this `/new-user/check-existing-email/EMAIL` (so its GET request and no CSRF is required) and also **throttle** protect the route, so attacker can not easily gather bunch of data. Does your app also make XHR requests after login?

Comment: Kyslik, yes, my app makes XHR requests after login.  How does that change things?

Comment: yes Kim, i prefer to put it under web .. cause middleware web has some classes you may use .. refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware ..